# Using es6 npm libraries in es5 without npm

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, ecmascript-5

I am writing a page which I have imported Vue from cdn. Other than not being able to use npm, I think I am okay with it.

At this point, I want to import libraries but they are needed to be installed from npm, but I don't have npm in this project. Is it possible to import the es6 library using `<script src=""></script>` way? Or do I have to go the build/compile way?

For example, this library: https://github.com/pespantelis/vue-typeahead - seems pretty small, and I tried importing main.js and common.js but they triggered syntax errors, however it works if I install it from npm on another project.

> ReferenceError: exports is not defined

I am asking this because I added axios from cdn with script src approach and it works.

Comment: Try add type="module" to script tag. https://medium.com/dev-channel/es6-modules-in-chrome-canary-m60-ba588dfb8ab7

Comment: vue-typeahead library is so small [120 lines](https://github.com/pespantelis/vue-typeahead/blob/master/src/main.js) that you can just convert it to es5 yourself and include it on your page. you could also transpile it locally or via "babel repl"

Comment: could use this: https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: @AhmedMusallam Will it use if I convert the syntax to es5?